# Controlling multiple windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm currently trying to learn WPF, and am writing a simple application to test some concepts which I've learned.

Basically once my application is run, a window is to be presented, acting as a login screen.  Once the user enters his details and pressed the login button, the window is to be closed and a new one is to be opened.

What would be the best approach for this? I recall having a number of problems doing something similar with WinForms, especially with window closing and disposing.

How can this be done?

Comment: What kind of problems are you expecting? Managing windows using Winforms is pretty trivial in my experience. The process you describe seems pretty straightforward to me. I'm sure this can be done in WPF the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have the "new one" be the main window of the app. Then in code behind for the "new one"'s constructor you could show the login window. if login succeeds then newOne launches. If it fails then the app quits.

```
public NewOne()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
  bool? result = login.ShowDialog();
  if (!result.HasValue || result.Value == false)
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on the login.ShowDialog() part? How would this return false?

Comment: I would recommend running that in the App.xaml.cs `OnStartup()` method instead of in the constructor for the MainWindow. I wrote an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861797/302677) earlier today if you want.

Comment: updated my hasty check of the showDialog result.  In your LoginWindow you'll do DialogResult = true; when login is successful and DialogResult=false when login fails.  The dialogresult is returned via ShowDialog().  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx