# Resizing window when view changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a WPF/Prism/MVVM application with a logon screen followed by several user screens (customer summary, order detail, etc.) The logon screen is smaller than the other screens. How do I get the window to resize when I switch from my logon screen to the next screen?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not either [use separate Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861797/302677), or have a full-sized window with the login centered on it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, not sure if what I did was 'right' but it works. What I ended up doing was creating a 'ShellWindowService'. This service was then registered (I use Unity) and exposed a ChangeWindowSize function.

Then basically, I could access the service either from DI or from hitting the ServiceLocator

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Common.Services.ShellWindowService>();
```

Now, I can use this service to change the size of the shell window from anywhere in the application by simply using the ShellWindowService.

Answer (score 0):

I Used `OnNavigatedTo` exposed by `INavigationAware` to intercept the navigation and change the main window size, this how the code looks like:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {

            var activeView = navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.ActiveViews.First() as UserControl;
            var window = Window.GetWindow(activeView);
            window.Width = activeView.Width;
            window.Height = activeView.Height;
        }
```