# Passing Parameters from one view model to another in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

As I continue to adapt to the new world of wpf and mvvm I find myself with another problem which is proving to be a little vexing.

In windows forms if I needed a new form to take a parameter I simply passed the information that I needed to that form's constructor.  As Winforms is essentially a code behind model anyway this wasn't an issue.

I now find myself with a MainWindow (controlled by MainWindowViewModel) and a Login (controlled by LoginViewModel) which is shown as a dialog first.  I have sorted the issue of the missing dialog result and I can get the main window to show after closing the login dialog.

The login dialog is shown and responded to in the Application startup with the following code;

```
dim dlg As New Login

    If dlg.ShowDialog() = True Then

    Else
       Current.Shutdown(0)
    End If
```

and I use the use the following in the code behind of the login window to take care of showing the main window when the login dialog closes;

```
Public Sub New

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
   Application.Current.ShutdownMode =ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClosed(e As EventArgs)
MyBase.OnClosed(e)
Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose
End Sub
```

Now the Mainwindow already knows that it's datacontext is MainWindoViewModel because I set that up when designing it with blend, so how do I pass any parameters that I want to pass from the LoginViewModel to the MainWindowViewModel?

I can read c# but would prefer vb if possible.  I know that this is something that I will want to be doing often so if there is a generic way to do this then that's the way I'd like to go.

Thanks

Comment: Typically you'd use some kind of messaging system to pass data between unrelated ViewModels, however in your situation with the Login and Main ViewModels, I wouldn't create MainViewModel until after the Login was successful, and I'd pass it the data it needs in the constructor. I have an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861797/302677) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Mvvm frameworks generally implement some kind of messaging system to allow data to be moved between viewmodels or sometimes between viewmodel and view.

You can look at the way messaging is handled in some of the more popular frameworks such as MvvmLight or MvvmCross. It's usually just like an event that uses a weak reference to prevent tight coupling, so you can register for a type of message and then from another viewmodel you publish a message to any registered listeners.

So you will either need to implement your own kind of messenger, or now might be a time to look at starting to use a third party framework, unless you have specific reasons for avoiding this.